# owl carousel 2 all items showing when the container width goes 100% on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel, tailwind-css

I'm trying to display a single item on all screens which are working fine and display a single item till 640px screen size using tailwindcss framework. But when the container width goes 100% on less than 640px screen, the owl carousel all items showing horizontally. I tried multiple solutions from the internet including stackoverflow but unable to fix that issue. Here's my code:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="slider-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme ">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/image/gallery-image-1.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/image/gallery-image-2.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/image/gallery-image-3.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the owl carousel settings are:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      singleItem: true,
      items: 1,
      loop: true,
      margin: 10,
      nav: true,
    });
  });
```

As I mentioned above the only issue is when the container size goes 100% on less than 640px screen then all items appeared in a row instead of a single item. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I got help from other platform. In my case, I used the grid in the top-level outer div. That's why the carousel not working properly for small screen. Thanks